# Why does the page reload on first button click?

Tags: php, jquery, woocommerce

Simple AJAX search which displays WooCommerce products with a category filter.

When I click add to cart for the first time only, page refreshes and does not show the view cart option.

When I click for the second time, it shows view cart as normal without reloading the page.

How can I fix this page loading issue which appears on the first click only?

```
    function perform_product_search() {
        $searchQuery = isset($_POST['search_query']) ? sanitize_text_field($_POST['search_query']) : '';
        $categoryFilter = isset($_POST['category_filter']) ? $_POST['category_filter'] : array();
    
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page' => -1, // Display all products
            's' => $searchQuery,
        );
    
        if (!empty($categoryFilter)) {
            $args['tax_query'] = array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                    'field' => 'term_id',
                    'terms' => $categoryFilter,
                    'operator' => 'IN',
                ),
            );
        }
    
        $loop = new WP_Query($args);
        $count = 0;
    
        ob_start(); // Start output buffering
    
        if ($loop->have_posts()) {
            echo '<div class="product-row">'; // Start the product row
            while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
                if ($count % 4 === 0 && $count > 0) {
                    echo '</div><div class="product-row">'; // Close previous row and start a new row after every 4 products
                }
                echo '<div class="col-md-3">'; // Add the new div with the desired class
                wc_get_template_part('content', 'product');
                echo '</div>'; // Close the new div
                $count++;
            endwhile;
            echo '</div>'; // Close the last product row
        } else {
            echo __('No products found');
        }
    
        wp_reset_postdata();
    
        $output = ob_get_clean(); // Get the buffered output
    
        // If no search query is provided, output all products
        if (empty($searchQuery) && empty($categoryFilter)) {
            $args_all = array(
                'post_type' => 'product',
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'posts_per_page' => -1, // Display all products
            );
    
            $loop_all = new WP_Query($args_all);
            $count_all = 0;
    
            ob_start(); // Start output buffering
    
            if ($loop_all->have_posts()) {
                echo '<div class="product-row">'; // Start the product row
                while ($loop_all->have_posts()) : $loop_all->the_post();
                    if ($count_all % 4 === 0 && $count_all > 0) {
                        echo '</div><div class="product-row">'; // Close previous row and start a new row after every 4 products
                    }
                    echo '<div class="col-md-3">'; // Add the new div with the desired class
                    wc_get_template_part('content', 'product');
                    echo '</div>'; // Close the new div
                    $count_all++;
                endwhile;
                echo '</div>'; // Close the last product row
            } else {
                echo __('No products found');
            }
    
            wp_reset_postdata();
    
            $output_all = ob_get_clean(); // Get the buffered output
            if (empty($output)) {
                $output = $output_all; // Use the output of all products if no search query output is available
            }
        }
    
        echo $output; // Output the products
    
        die();
    }
    
    
    add_action('wp_ajax_perform_product_search', 'perform_product_search');
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_perform_product_search', 'perform_product_search');
    
    // AJAX add to cart
    function add_to_cart() {
        $product_id = isset($_POST['product_id']) ? absint($_POST['product_id']) : 0;
        $quantity = isset($_POST['quantity']) ? absint($_POST['quantity']) : 1;
    
        if ($product_id > 0) {
            WC()->cart->add_to_cart($product_id, $quantity);
    
            // Return updated cart fragments
            ob_start();
            woocommerce_mini_cart();
            $mini_cart = ob_get_clean();
    
            wp_send_json_success(array(
                'fragments' => apply_filters('woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments', array(
                    '.widget_shopping_cart_content' => $mini_cart,
                )),
            ));
        }
    
        wp_send_json_error();
    }
    add_action('wp_ajax_add_to_cart', 'add_to_cart');
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_add_to_cart', 'add_to_cart');
    
    
    // Shortcode implementation
    function realtime_product_search_shortcode() {
        ob_start();
    
        // Get product categories
        $categories = get_terms(array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'hide_empty' => true,
        ));?>
        <div class="realtime-product-search">
            <input type="text" id="product-search" placeholder="Search for products..." />
            <div id="category-filter">
                <h4>Filter by Category:</h4>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="category_filter[]" value="" /> Any Category
                </label>
                <?php foreach ($categories as $category) : ?>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="category_filter[]" value="<?php echo $category->term_id; ?>" />
                        <?php echo $category->name; ?>
                    </label>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </div>
            <div id="search-results"></div>
        </div>
        <?php return ob_get_clean();
    }
    add_shortcode('realtime_product_search', 'realtime_product_search_shortcode');
```

JS file

```
    (function($){
    $(document).ready(function ($) {
        var typingTimer;
        var doneTypingInterval = 500; // Adjust the interval as needed (in milliseconds)

        function performProductSearch() {
            clearTimeout(typingTimer);

            typingTimer = setTimeout(function() {
                var searchQuery = $('#product-search').val();
                var categoryFilter = [];

                $('input[name="category_filter[]"]:checked').each(function() {
                    var value = $(this).val();
                    if (value !== '') {
                        categoryFilter.push(value);
                    }
                });

                $.ajax({
                    url: realtime_product_search_ajax.ajax_url,
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {
                        action: 'perform_product_search',
                        search_query: searchQuery,
                        category_filter: categoryFilter
                    },
                    beforeSend: function() {
                        $('#search-results').html('Searching...');
                    },
                    success: function(response) {
                        $('#search-results').html(response);
                    }
                });
            }, doneTypingInterval);
        }

        // Trigger search on input change
        $('#product-search, input[name="category_filter[]"]').on('change keyup', function() {
            performProductSearch();
        });

        // Add to cart functionality
        $(document).on('submit', '.add-to-cart-form', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var form = $(this);
            var product_id = form.find('.product-id').val();
            var quantity = form.find('.quantity').val();

            $.ajax({
                url: realtime_product_search_ajax.ajax_url,
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    action: 'add_to_cart',
                    product_id: product_id,
                    quantity: quantity
                },
                beforeSend: function() {
                    // Show loading/spinner if desired
                },
                success: function(response) {
                    // Update cart fragment
                    $(document.body).trigger('wc_fragment_refresh');

                    // Show success message or perform other actions
                    alert('Product added to cart.');

                    // Show View Cart button
                    var viewCartUrl = response.fragments.cart_url;
                    var viewCartButton = '<a href="' + viewCartUrl + '" class="button wc-forward">View Cart</a>';
                    form.after(viewCartButton);
                }
            });
        });
    });

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Not sure, but maybe you need to add `e.preventDefault();` also to `.on('change keyup', function(e) {`

Comment: Do you have an error in the console? If there are errors in JavaScript your script will not run and it will submit the form. Try in DevTools to enable "preserve logs" so you can see if there was an error before submitting.

Comment: Adding e.preventDefault(); did not work in this case, the result is the same @LoicTheAztec

Comment: @jcubic
See my screenshot below. 1 represents the first click, it seems to call admin-ajax.php directly after. 2,3,4,5,6 represents the other calls which are as normal with no page reload (view cart displayed)
https://prnt.sc/PslF1Xf7JsA_

Comment: The second call that one with `admin-ajax.php` is also ajax call but it seems that without query string. add `console.log(realtime_product_search_ajax.ajax_url)` and you will see what is the URL you're calling.

Comment: Ultimately, I never found the cause, but did find a solution. When I added 4+ products, I did not experience the issue. Previously with only 2 it occurred.